# Need help on setting up Stack Alert chromium extension

Tags: google-chrome-extensions

I found the [stack alert extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bpficcollblmkmoofnbnfhibdhfolamm) on the chrome web store, but I have trouble setting it up.

I always get the following message when I click on its button:

[image: app auth]

So it seems to me that the cookie isn't shared.
What should I try now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the Extension icon. A popup will come which will allow the extension to fetch the oAUth key and Authenticate.

[image]

Once you click on Authorize, it should ask your to Approve the authorization. If this button isn't shown first try logging into [Stack Exchange openID endpoint](http://openid.stackexchange.com), if you're using that.

[image]

If you don't see the Extension Icon, head over to `chrome://extensions` or Click on the Chrome Menu icon & select extensions. Search for Stack Alert and click on Show Button.

[image]